# Add to Cart button not showing for variable product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried a lot of things. No results.
My add to cart button for variable product does not work. it works for simple product. but for variable product, it is not even shown up.
I have edited the twenty-thirteen theme to incorporate my custom html theme and over ridden the css and everything else that existed.
When i change the theme to 2015/2014, it works fine. But with my custom theme, it doesnt work.

I have tried [WooCommerce jQuery Cookie Fix](http://splashingpixels.com/woocommerce-jquery-cookie-js-error/)
and added a hook to function.php as :

```
  /*Add to Cart for variable products*/
  function fix_woo_var_cart()
  {
  wp_enqueue_script('add-to-cart-variation', '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js',array('jquery'),'1.0',true);
   }
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','fix_woo_var_cart');
 ?>
```

Nothing however seems to work! Please help!

Comment: in variable products when u select attribute variation from drop down  menu then "add to cart" button will visible

Comment: Yes that is how it's supposed to work. But it isn't!

Comment: ok are you assigning prices to variable products

Comment: Check your browser's developer console. You will see any script errors. Have you modified any of WooCommerce's templates? (You can also check for outdated templates in the WooCommerce settings) That is a very common cause of add to cart ceasing to work for variable products.

Comment: apparently id commented wp_head() and wp_footer(); for some reason. Uncommented that and all's fine.

Answer (score 0):

apparently id commented wp_head() and wp_footer(); for some reason.
i was told that isn't necessary while i learnt to integrate html into wp. therefore, the issues.
 Uncommented that and all's fine.:)